Protected Local Storage is very slow
I have 13 parameters that when a user log in website will be set like this:
`ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("iduser", iduser);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("unitid", unitid);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("branchid", branchid);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("organid", organid);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defuser", defuser);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defbranch", defbranch);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defunit", defunit);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defproduct", defproduct);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defpointofbody", defpointofbody);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defdegree", defdegree);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defvisit", defvisit);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("defpatient", defpatient);
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("report", report);`

after login I want to have this values in 2 razor pages. One of the pages is my navmenu layout and the other one is mainmenu.
so in both I have this code:
 var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("iduser");
iduser = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("unitid");
unitid = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("branchid");
branchid = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<int>("organid");
organid = result.Success ? result.Value : 0;
var result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defuser");
defuser = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defbranch");
defbranch = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defunit");
defunit = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defvisit");
defvisit = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defdegree");
defdegree = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defpointofbody");
defpointofbody = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defpatient");
defpatient = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("defproduct");
defproduct = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;
result1 = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<bool>("report");
report = result1.Success ? result1.Value : false;

the problem is that it is very slow loading this parameters. How can I speed up this Process?

Have you tried using a single object?

i made a combination of all parameters to a string and made one object. it's better but i was thinking if there is a way to set this parameters one time for all of menus of the website, for example when a user logs in set them one time and when change the page never read them again

See my answer below.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis very useful . Thank you

First of all, creating one object having all those fields is the best way to go.
public class SessionData
{
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int OrganId { get; set; }
    public bool DefUser { get; set; }
    public bool DefBranch { get; set; }
    public bool DefUnit { get; set; }
    public bool DefVisit { get; set; }
    public bool DefDegree { get; set; }
    public bool DefPointOfBody { get; set; }
    public bool DefPatient { get; set; }
    public bool DefProduct { get; set; }
    public bool Report { get; set; }
}

Create a State Management Service, let's call it SessionStateService, this one will manage these relevant data across your web app during the session.
Register it as Scoped, or even as Singleton if it's a Blazor WebAssmebly application.
For example, your service can be something like this:
public class SessionDataService
{
    private readonly ProtectedSessionStore _protectedSessionStore;
    public SessionData SessionData { get; private set; }

    public SessionDataService(ProtectedSessionStore protectedSessionStore)
    {
        _protectedSessionStore = protectedSessionStore;
        SessionData = new SessionData(); // Initialize with default values
    }

    public async Task LoadSessionDataAsync()
    {
        var result = await _protectedSessionStore.GetAsync<string>("sessionData");
        if (result.Success && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Value))
        {
            SessionData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionData>(result.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            SessionData = new SessionData(); // Initialize with default values if not found
        }
    }

    public async Task StoreSessionDataAsync()
    {
        var sessionDataJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(SessionData);
        await _protectedSessionStore.SetAsync("sessionData", sessionDataJson);
    }

    public void SetSessionData(SessionData sessionData)
    {
        SessionData = sessionData;
    }
}

You can eventually access the stored data this way:
@page "/example"
@inject SessionDataService SessionDataService

<h3>Example Page</h3>

<p>IdUser: @SessionDataService.SessionData.IdUser</p>

<button @onclick="UpdateSessionData">Update Session Data</button>

@code {
    private void UpdateSessionData()
    {
        SessionDataService.SessionData.IdUser = 123;
        // Save changes back to ProtectedSessionStore
        SessionDataService.StoreSessionDataAsync();
    }
}


i have a problem how is it possible to cast a string to SessionData class while reading the data from storage ?

@KasraGhavami as the data is being stored a JSON string in the local storage, we can use SessionData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionData>(result.Value); to deserialize the string, which means to map the JSON(result.Value) from a string representation of an object to an instance of the model itself. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Here's an example showing how to build a service to work with the storage.
My simple data object:
public record MyData(string Value = "");

A service:
public class DataService
{
    private ProtectedLocalStorage _storage;
    public MyData Data { get; private set; } = new($"Default values set at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    public event EventHandler<MyData>? DataChanged;

    public const string StorageName = "mydata";
    public DataService(ProtectedLocalStorage protectedLocalStorage)
    {
        _storage = protectedLocalStorage;
    }

    public async ValueTask GetAsync()
    {
        var result = await _storage.GetAsync<MyData>(StorageName);

        if (result.Success)
        {
            this.Data = result.Value ?? new($"Default values set at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            this.DataChanged?.Invoke(this, this.Data);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask SetAsync()
    {
        await _storage.SetAsync(StorageName, this.Data);
        this.DataChanged?.Invoke(this, this.Data);
    }

    public async ValueTask SetValueAsync(string value)
    {
        this.Data = this.Data with {Value = value };
        await SetAsync();
    }
}

Registered in DI:
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddScoped<DataService>();

MainLayout.  Added here to try and get the values on first load of the SPA.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject DataService dataService

//...
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await dataService.GetAsync();
    }
}

Home to demo interaction with the service:
@page "/"
@inject DataService DataService
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    @this.DataService.Data.Value
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OnClickAsync">Update</button>
</div>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.DataService.DataChanged += this.OnDataChanged;
    }
    private async Task OnClickAsync()
    {
        await DataService.SetValueAsync($"Last Updated at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }

    private void OnDataChanged(object? sender, MyData data)
    {
        this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.DataService.DataChanged -= this.OnDataChanged;
    }
}

Note the need for the event if you want to update the UI to display the information.
